# Merging two text files based on a common column in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, csv

I'm attempting to merge select columns from two text files based on a common column. I'm doing this so that I can import it into MySQL. Obviously, in SQL this would be a simple query to get the information but I actually want a separate and permanent table with the specified join therefore I need to create this text file for the import.

This is the code that I'm currently using:

```
import csv

with open('locations.txt', 'rb') as l,\
     open('checkins.txt','rb') as c,\
     open('location.txt','w') as location:
     writer = csv.writer(location, delimiter='\t')

    for line in c:
       words = line.split()
    for lines in l:
       word = lines.split()
    writer.writerow([word[:], words[3], words[4], words[6:16]])
```

Here is the sample output:

`['220811', 'Flemington', '2010-10-23'] 59.31297463 '\t' 18.02006155 '\t' ['59.2968', '18.0313', '1.91024672383817', '12420', 'Bandhagen', 'SE']`

(As an aside, I keep getting apostrophes and brackets in my output. Is there a way to get rid of those? I didn't have the problem until I imported csv and used the writerow method using brackets so I'm guessing that's the problem.)

The output I want is the data joined on column 1 from locations.txt and column 5 from the checkins.txt. Should I find a way to sort the information in both text files based on the columns I want to join?

Also, there shouldn't be any different information in column 1 in locations.txt from column 5 but there will be duplicates in column 5 in the checkins.txt file. Is there a proper way to handle this? (I would like to keep the duplicates associated with the column 1 values in locations.txt)

Comment: Why not just do this in SQL by selecting the join into a new table?

Comment: This may be a really stupid question but I can do that? I can create a permanent table in the database after having joined them?

Comment: You'll need `INSERT INTO [tablename] SELECT ....` for MySQL. The MySQL Documentation is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Comment: I'm still attempting to load one of my files into the DB. It's 79.6MB and I keep getting booted out when the wait lock is exceeded. Once I fix this issue I'll let you know. I looked it up and it appears that I could easily join them like you suggested though.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question detailing the method with a better explanation and some example SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the array before printing it:

```
writer.writerow("\t".join(word[:] + words[3] + words[4] + words[6:16]))
```

Also, you are overwriting the variable words from l. So, you aren't getting what you want. You probably need something like words2 = lines.split() for the second file's output.

Comment: I'm not sure if I typed it incorrectly but this wouldn't build when I tried it.

Comment: Sorry, you need to surround the single elements in a list: ..."\t".join(word[:] + words[3:5] + words[6:16])  I shortened it a bit by merging 3 and 4 together with words[3:5]. The way I wrote it originally was trying to append a string to a list which isn't allowed in python. I also noticed that you named your lists differently (words and word)...So, my comment about words is a little incorrect. Though, it is good to be more clear when creating new variables with similar but different contents

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved by simply selecting the join into a new table.

In MySQL this uses the [`INSERT... SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) like so:

```
INSERT INTO New_Table
  SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t2.field1
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.PK = t2.table1_FK
```

As such you should try to keep such an operation inside the database for both performance reasons and to make your steps more easily repeatable rather than having to dump the query to a CSV and then join the query separately (although you could have skipped this step by writing the join query first and then outputting that to a CSV but it's still the wrong approach here) and then inserting that back into the database.